# 'Greater than or equal' and 'less than or equal' CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have to query something that has a where condition with `>=` and `=<` but I have no luck. This is in **CODEIGNITER**.

This is the natural way in mysql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count, `product_key`.`client_name`, 
`product_key`.`contact_email`, `product_key`.`status`, `product_key`.`id`, 
`payment`.`paymentdate`, (payment.id) as pid, `payment`.`subscription_type` 
FROM (`product_key`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `payment` ON `payment`.`keyid`=`product_key`.`id` 
WHERE `payment`.`paymentdate` >= '2013-08-01' 
    AND `payment`.`paymentdate` =< '2013-08-31' 
    AND `status` = 'purchased' 
GROUP BY `product_key`.`id` 
ORDER BY `client_name` asc
```

And this is what I have:

```
    return $this->db
    ->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count')
    ->select('product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid,payment.subscription_type')
    ->from('product_key')          
    ->where('payment.paymentdate >=', $month_start)
    ->where('payment.paymentdate =<', $month_end)
    ->where('status', 'purchased')
    ->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'left outer')
    ->order_by('client_name', "asc")
    ->group_by('product_key.id')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Maybe someone could help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using between ??

Comment: Or try Explicitly converting the hard coded date to date

Comment: @ashutosh-arya I've never used between in any of my queries before. Especially now that I'm using codeigniter as my framework. But I'll search how to use it now. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @AshutoshArya: `BETWEEN` is just syntactic sugar, but perhaps a `DATE_FORMAT` would help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `=<` to `<=`.

I also tested your current query in phpmyadmin, because i could not believe that it does not throw an error. But mine does it. So your query should not work in phpmyadmin.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=< ...' at line ...
```

Answer (score 14):

Try to change the `=<` to `<=` like

```
->where('payment.paymentdate >=', $month_start)
->where('payment.paymentdate <=', $month_end)
```

And **better** but not cumpolsury to join the table before the where condition.Now your query should be like

```
->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count')
->select('product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid,payment.subscription_type')
->from('product_key')         
->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'left outer')    
->where('payment.paymentdate >=', $month_start)
->where('payment.paymentdate <=', $month_end)
->where('status', 'purchased')
->order_by('client_name', "asc")
->group_by('product_key.id')
->get()
```

Comment: The original SQL does not contain any `OR` :-?

Comment: @Gautam: A rollback and afterwards add the same again? Why?

Comment: Actually I want to suggest him to use or_where but It may not useful for him...I have edited thax.

Comment: @TobiasKun its my typo.Just I have copied it from above code.So I just corrected myself

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db
->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count, product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid, payment.subscription_type', false)
->from('product_key')
->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'LEFT OUTER')
->where('payment.paymentdate >=', '2013-08-01')
->where('payment.paymentdate <=', '2013-08-31')
->where('status', 'purchased')
->group_by('product_key.id')
->order_by('client_name', 'asc')
->get();
```

Comment: As much as I'd want to do that, but I can't. My variables vary depending on the current date.

Answer (score 1):

from what i know, you can write them like this

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count, product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid, payment.subscription_type', false);
$this->db->where('payment.paymentdate >= "2013-08-01"');
$this->db->where('payment.paymentdate <= "2013-08-31"');
$this->db->where('status', 'purchased');
$this->db->group_by('product_key.id');
$this->db->order_by('client_name', 'asc');
$this->db->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'LEFT OUTER')
$this->db->get('product_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(ph_payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'");
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(ph_payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= '$startdate'");
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(ph_payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') <= '$enddate'");
```